# how to run a powershell script as a windows service from inside a Java program?

Tags: java, powershell, wmi, wmi-service, j-interop

I have the following code that runs a windows service from inside Java.The code uses JInterop Java library, JInterop is a pure Java COM client for windows COM server. More details of JIntop are available here [http://fishi.devtail.io/weblog/2015/01/21/pure-java-dcom-bridge-j-interop/]

```
    String cmdFile = "service.bat";
results = wbemServices_dispatch.callMethodA(
                "Get", new Object[]{ new JIString("Win32_Process"),
                new Integer(0), JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM()});

        IJIDispatch wbemObjectSet_dispatch = (IJIDispatch)JIObjectFactory.narrowObject(
                (results[0]).getObjectAsComObject());
results = wbemObjectSet_dispatch.callMethodA("Create",
                new Object[]{ new JIString(targetFilePrefix + cmdFile),
                JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(),
                JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM()});
```

Is it possible to run a powershell file(.ps1) as a service in the same manner as above using the same library, or in some other way.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a batch file which, in-turns, can trigger a powershell script like this:

```
@echo off
Powershell.exe set-executionpolicy remotesigned -File  C:\folder\MyScript.ps1
pause
```

Save it as ***"Trigger_ps.bat"***

Then you can use the **sc command** to create a windows service by mentioning this batch file path like this:

```
SC CREATE PS_Trigger_Service Displayname= "PS_Trigger_Service" binpath= "C:\folder\Trigger_ps.bat" start= auto
```

This should solve your purpose.

Comment: can I create and then start/stop/delete this service in a remote machine?

Comment: For sure , you can do that. @Manjur