# How do I run a PowerShell script as a service?

Tags: powershell, netstat

I created the script below to check my application's port 2025 and log the number of connections.

I need this script to run as a service on Windows with the name `netstat_2025`. Does anyone know if there is such a possibility?

I do not want to use the Task Scheduler, but instead run the script as a service on Windows.

script SCTT521CTO.ps1

```
$startTime =  (Get-Date).ToString("dd_MM_yyyy")
$LogDate = ((get-date).ToLocalTime()).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")
$hostname = hostname

$portTServer = 8000
$FileTserver = netstat -ano | findstr "8000"

$LogTserver = $LogDate + " - Quantidade de Conexoes na porta " + $portTServer + ": " + $FileTserver.count + " - Servidor: " + $hostname
$LogTserver | Out-File -Append D:\SCTT521CTO\netstat_$startTime.log

$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)
$path = "D:\SCTT521CTO\*"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force
```

script service.ps1

```
# Desired name of the service
$serviceName = 'netstat_2025'

# Get the full path to powershell.exe
$powershellPath = ( Get-Command powershell ).Source

# The path to the script you want to run as a service
$serviceScriptPath = D:\scripts\SCTT521CTO.ps1

# The arguments to pass to the powershell executable each time the service starts
$args = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File "{0}"' -f $serviceScriptPath

# Install the service using nssm
nssm install $serviceName $powershellPath $args

# See that the service is registered and check its status
Get-Service $serviceName
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to run a powershell script as a windows service from inside a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927184/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-a-windows-service-from-inside-a-java-program)

Comment: Have a look at [New-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-6)

Comment: I followed the example, but to no avail, the service was created, but unable to start it.

Comment: sc.exe create PS_Trigger_Service Displayname= "PS_Trigger_Service" binpath= "D:\SCRIPTS\SCTT521CTO.ps1" start= auto

Comment: Returns an error while trying to start the service.
 "Erro 193: 0Xc1"

Comment: It sounds like you need to run this as a scheduled task rather than as a service. (Services are special applications that respond to control requests.)

Comment: How scheduled task works, however in my work it is not feasible to create this way, so I thought of running as a service in Windows.

Comment: Why is it not feasible?

Comment: @LeandrodeMatos see my updated answer

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I tried to create the script below using nssm but the service does not start, returning me the error "Service netstat_8000 ran for less than 1500 milliseconds. Restart will be delayed by 1"

Comment: My answer already covers this but if you want your service to run until stopped, you need to put your main logic in an infinite loop, or at least a loop that won't terminate until a condition is met where you want the service to stop. Otherwise, your service ends because you reached the end of your code. This isn't nssm specific, this is a rule of service design. In your case you'll probably want to make sure at the end of the loop you sleep for some number of seconds at the end of the main loop otherwise your service is likely to eat a bunch of CPU time.

Comment: I updated my answer to show what I mean by "put your main logic in an infinite loop"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer failed to take into account that you still need to implement the service control interfaces, which `powershell.exe` does not implement. I did look into some other methods of running a PowerShell script as a service, however.

One of the easier tools I came across that does this for you is `nssm` You can use [`nssm` (Non-Sucking Service Manager)](https://nssm.cc/) to register a new service and have it run your PowerShell script. You'll need to make sure your **script's main logic runs within an infinite loop** (as most long running programs or services do), and then you can use `nssm` to register a new service that will run your PowerShell script. Below is an example of putting your code into a main loop that doesn't terminate:

```
while( $true ) {
  $startTime =  (Get-Date).ToString("dd_MM_yyyy")
  $LogDate = ((get-date).ToLocalTime()).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff")
  $hostname = hostname

  $portTServer = 8000
  $FileTserver = netstat -ano | findstr "8000"

  $LogTserver = $LogDate + " - Quantidade de Conexoes na porta " + $portTServer + ": " + $FileTserver.count + " - Servidor: " + $hostname
  $LogTserver | Out-File -Append D:\SCTT521CTO\netstat_$startTime.log

  $limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)
  $path = "D:\SCTT521CTO\*"
  Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force

  # Add a sleep at the end of the loop to prevent the script from eating
  # too much CPU time
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

To register your script as a PowerShell service, you can use the following PowerShell code (note that if you install with `Chocolatey`, `nssm` will already be on the `PATH`, not sure if it is when you manually install):

```
# Desired name of the service
$serviceName = 'netstat_2025'

# Get the full path to powershell.exe
$powershellPath = ( Get-Command powershell ).Source

# The path to the script you want to run as a service
$serviceScriptPath = C:\path\to\service\script.ps1

# The arguments to pass to the powershell executable each time the service starts
$args = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File "{0}"' -f $serviceScriptPath

# Install the service using nssm
nssm install $serviceName $powershellPath $args

# See that the service is registered and check its status
Get-Service $serviceName
```

Your service should now be installed and able to be controlled like any other Windows service. The way this works is instead of registering `powershell.exe` as a service directly, it registers `nssm.exe` as the service executable instead, which **does** implement the correct service control handlers, and then runs whatever program you configured it to for this service (in this case, calling your script with `powershell.exe`).

Comment: Hello,

I created the service however trying to start it returns the error below:

"The service did not respond to the start request or control in a timely manner."

One solution I have tried so far was to create a key in the windows registry called ServicesPipeTimeout hoping that the error was that the wait time to start the service was too small, but unfortunately it did not resolve.

How can I proceed?

Should I change something in my code?

Comment: Damn, I thought this would work but it seems you still need to implement the .NET service interfaces within your script for this to work. I don't have time at the moment but I can update this tonight or tomorrow with how to do that from your script.

Comment: Looking at your script you'll also need your main bit to be an unterminating loop for when the service is running, otherwise it'll just stop because it hits the end of your code.

Comment: The main problem, of course, is that services are special executables that respond to control signals, and `powershell.exe` is not designed as a service. The OP should opt to run the script using a scheduled task instead.

Comment: Due to my work restrictions, all tasks in Scheduler are automatically deleted. Therefore I must create as a service.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I tried some ways but could not update the code, could you tell me how to proceed?

Comment: You cannot directly run a PowerShell script as a service because `powershell.exe` is not a service executable. How and why are all tasks in the scheduler automatically deleted? The Task Scheduler is a core OS component. Address that problem and run as a task, or use another tool that lets you schedule programs to run.

Comment: Still, there are cases where a long running service is more desirable than a scheduled task. Solving this problem is still useful to know. I'm updating my answer with how to achieve this correctly with PowerShell.

Comment: IMO a third-party tool is unnecessary when you can just run as a scheduled task.

Answer (score 5):

You can just download NSSM from nssm.cc them:

1. Run nssm in command line: nssm install YourServiceName
2. Set the informations:

- Path: Powershell path
- Startup directory: Your script directory
- Options: .\yourscript.ps1 -arg1 value -arg2 value -arg3 value

[image]

That's it.